# Exporting DataGrid in MVVM way

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

How do I export the contents of the DataGrid into a CSV file in an MVVM way?
My DataGrid contains 55 columns. All columns can be reordered or hidden.

The column order and visibility is controlled by the view model

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="File Size"
                    DisplayIndex="{Binding Source={StaticResource Spy}, Path=DataContext.Columns.FileSize.Index, FallbackValue=8, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    Visibility="{Binding Source={StaticResource Spy}, Path=DataContext.Columns.FileSize.IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}"
                    Binding="{Binding Sample.FileSize, TargetNullValue={StaticResource NullString}}"/>
```

Comment: Is this the standard .NET 4 DataGrid?

Comment: Yes. It is the standard WPF DataGrid

Comment: Are the visibility and sort order of your columns controlled in the ViewModel or in the View?

Comment: I updated my question regarding your question. Please look there. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify the solution found in [Scott Hanselman Blog Post about "From Linq To CSV"](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/back-to-basics-keep-it-simple-and-develop-your-sense-of-smell-from-linq-to-csv) to only use the Columns that are not hidden and to sort the columns in the same order as in your ViewModel.

```
public string ToCsv(IEnumerable items)
{
    var csvBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(prop => Columns[prop.Name].FileSize.IsVisible).OrderBy(prop => Column[prop.Name].FileSize.Index).ToArray();
    
    foreach (T item in items)
    {
        string line = string.Join(",",properties.Select(p => p.GetValue(item, null));
        csvBuilder.AppendLine(line);
    }
    return csvBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Comment: The problem is I will have a lot of duplicate code. XAML: <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Sample.FileSize and EXPORT: writeCell(Sample.FileSize). 55 of these. I'm thinking of statically defining the binding paths then generate the XAML programatically. The export function will also use the binding paths

Comment: I don't understand how the XAML duplication has anything to do with the export logic

Answer (score 1):

If you use MVVM, then your ViewModel have to contain all changes of your Grid. You should create a `button`, for example, and `Command`, where `Execute` body will looks like this:

```
{
     SaveMyListToCSV(parameter);
}
```

Parameter should be or your `DataGrid`, or your source.